# É possível manter um branch com alterações pendentes no Git?

Tags: git, commit

Imagine que eu tenha no branch master um commit de um arquivo `texte.txt`. Então eu crio um branch chamado `teste2`, faço checkout nele e crio lá um arquivo chamado `teste2.txt`, mas não faço o commit.

Se eu der um `git checkout master` e verificar o `git status`, ele consideda as alterações (no caso a criação de `teste2.txt`) como pertencente ao branch master, mesmo que eu tenha feito essas alterações quando estava no branch `teste2`.

Tem um jeito de manter essas alterações no branch `teste2` sem ter de fazer o commit? Pois pode ser que eu não queira fazer o commit, se ainda não concluí o que estou implementando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Só é possivel ter alteracoes pendentes no branch que está actualmente a ser usado.

Quando se tem alterações pendentes, e se pretende mudar de branch, é habitual guardar as alteracoes numa [stash](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing).

Por exemplo, usando o caso de uso na pergunta, se estivermos no branch `teste2`, podemos guardar as alteracoes numa stash assim:

```
git stash                                //stash anonima    
git stash save "adicionado teste2.txt"   //stash com nome
```

Agora, podemos mudar para o branch `master` e trabalhar noutros ficheiros.

```
git checkout master
```

Quando voltarmos ao branch `teste2`, basta *aplicar* a stash novamente para restaurar o estado inicial:

```
git checkout teste2
git stash list                           //ver lista das stashes

git stash apply                          //aplica a ultima stash que foi gravada
git stash apply stash@{0}                //aplica a stash no index 0
git stash apply stash^{/adicionado}      //aplica uma stash especifica (pesquisa por regex)
```

Nota: Quando se faz *apply*, a stash continua guardada na stack. Se quisermos aplicar *e* apagar a stash, usa-se `git stash pop`. Também podemos usar `git stash list` para listar todas as stashes actualmente na stack.

[Git stash man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Comment: Boa resposta! Era bem o que eu estava procurando. =)